# onPause called twice when using android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Tags: android, landscape, android-lifecycle

My app can only be used in landscape. 
But i noticed when setting android:screenOrientation="landscape"
in my manifest the onPause is called twice. 
Probably all activity livecycles will get called twice.

How can i avoid this, and is this normal?

**Edit**

I use a android annotations library (https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations).
Here is my activity declaration in my manifest.

```
 <activity
        android:name="MyActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: i set android:screenOrientation="landscape" in manifest, and just call  onPause() once

Comment: can you show your code?